# Coupled Non Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve the system:

(1) $\frac{dx}{dt} = x/(x + y)$,

(2) $\frac{dy}{dt} = y/(x + y)$

I have tried differentiating (1) and (2) to remove the effects of y and x respectively without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use that $dx/dt + dy/dt = 1$ to eliminate one variable

Comment: Good idea, having a look now

Comment: Also, the vector field is just a rescaling of $(x,y)$, so up to a time reparametrization, the solutions agree with those of $(\dot x,\dot y)=(x,y)$